# Eclipse juno c++ debug error 193

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-juno

This happened the first time I've tried debugging with Eclipse juno C++:

[image]

> `Error in final launch sequence` 
>   `Failed to execute MI command:` 
>   `-exec-run` 
>   `Error message from debugger back end:` 
>   `Error creating process <full path>... (error 193)`

Running the program using "Run" instead of "Debug" works just fine but when I try debug I get this. I googled about a bit and found somewhere that I should remove any spaces from the directory; I did that but it still isn't working.

The version of eclipse I'm running is:

- Eclipse `IDE for C/C++ Developers`
- Version: `Juno Service Release 1`
- - Build id: `20120920-0800`

Edit:
Problem is sorted! It was because I had forgot the space in my user account name. Because I couldn't be bothered to go through a load of mess changing the folder name in users I just moved my workspace folders straight to my C Drive so the path that it follows is now: C:\eclipse\WorkspaceC++

Thank you very much to john in the comments :)

Comment: I would defintely try removing parentheses from your path as well. No idea if that will help in this case but parens in a path is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Are you sure you have removed the spaces? From the look of that dialog box you still have a space between 'Admiral' and 'Joseph'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OP edit: *Problem is sorted!*

It was because I had forgot the space in my user account name.

Because I couldn't be bothered to go through a load of mess changing the folder name in users I just moved my workspace folders straight to my C Drive so the path that it follows is now: `C:\eclipse\WorkspaceC++`